# Image gets slightly erased on SWT/Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have an Eclipse plugin which includes a view. The view has several icons in the toolbar. I'm experiencing a very strange problem: on Windows, in some occasions (after prolonged use), one of the icons gets slightly erased. This does not happen on other platforms.

This looks like a memory leak or some other resource misuse, but I just can't figure out where. The rest of the icons, which are initialized and used in the exact same manner are not affected.

I tried working with Sleak, but I really don't see anything out of the ordinary. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem...

The images in the Toolbar are 16X16 pixels. My mistake: some of the icons were 14X14 or 14X16. This caused this mayhem. It should be noted that the affected icon was actually in the right size. It's other icons that were wrong, affecting this icon. This made it harder to find the problem, since I was focusing on what's wrong with that button.